# Image output from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im learn php,try develops a little blog for myself. I have a problem.When I pull information from the database, everything is displayed except the picture. In code i try save picture in img folder, there is an addition to the database, but there is no saving to the folder.And this is probably why there is no image output.
I ask for help. Sorry for my English. Thanks!

//AddPost

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../DB.php';


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['button-post']))  {
$error ='';



    if (!empty($_FILES['img']['name'])){
        $img = time() . "_" . $_FILES['img']['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['img']['type'];
        $destination = "../img/" . $img;


        if (strpos($fileType, 'image') === false) {
            $error = "The uploaded file is not an image!!";
        }else{
            $result = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $destination);

            if ($result){
                 $_POST['img'] =$img ;
                 // tt( $img);
            }else{
                $error = " Error uploading image to server";
            }
        }
    }else{
        $error= "Error getting picture";
    }

  $title = trim( $_POST['title']);
  $texton = trim( $_POST['texton']);


    if (strlen($title) <= 2 ) {
      $error = '';
    }
    elseif (strlen($texton)<= 5 )  {
      $error = '';
    }

      else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `posts`(`title`, `texton`, `img`) VALUES(?,?,?)";

    $query = $connect->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute([$title,$texton,$img]);



 }
}
```

//index

```
<?php
                     require_once 'DB.php';
                     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts`  ORDER BY`id`DESC";
                     $query = $connect->query($sql);
                 

     while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)):
    
        ?>
                        <div class="titlePost col-12 col-md-9">
                           <h2>
                          <a href="#"><?=$row->title;?></a>
                           </h2>
                           <div class="imgPost col-12 col-md-4">
                             <img src="/img .<?= $row->img?>;" alt="postik">
                           </div>
                            <p> <?=$row->texton;?></p>
                        </div>
        
        <?php  endwhile; ?>
    
    
    
    
          <form action="addPost_form.php" method="post" class="row justify-content-center">
                <h2>Add Post</h2>
                <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4 err">
                    <p><?=$error?></p>
                </div>
        
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-6">
                  <label for="title">Title</label>
                  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
                </div>
        
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-8">
                  <label for="texton">Сontent</label>
                  <textarea type="text" name="texton" id="texton" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                </div>
        
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4">
                      <input name="img" enctype='multipart/form-data' type="file" class="form-control" id="img">
                  </div>
        
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4">
        
            </div>
                <div class="w-100"></div>
                <div class="mb-3 col-12 col-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" name="button-post">Add</button>
        
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you show form as well from which you are uploading the image

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is the proper data stored in the database? Is the markup generated properly? Is it just the file that is missing?

Comment: Most probably you are forgetting to pass the enctype="mutlipart/form-data" parameter in form tag if your image is not getting saved in the folder

Comment: @NicoHaase
stuck on the fact that the image is not displayed on the screen.
The file transfer itself is, I checked it with a debug function.
The name of the file and its extension are saved in the database.
But there is no image in the output.I will add a filling form

Comment: You moved the uploaded file to `'../img/' . $imgName`, but then you output only `<img src="<?= $row->imgName?>;"` in your HTML. So where did the `../img/` part go?

Comment: @CBroe    I'm sorry. This is how it happens. But it didn't change anything     <img src="../img/<?= $row->imgName?>;" alt="postik">

Comment: So where are those files and folders located? You are going up one folder level from the location that `addPost_form.php` is in, and then into a folder `img` there. If `addPost_form.php` itself is located in the document root, then this won't work - you can not access folders _outside_ of the document root via HTTP.

Comment: I see two issues: absence of  enctype="multipart/form-data" at the form opening tag as vivek modi pointed out and wrong folder path as CBroe said. If the img folder is at the same level as addPost_form.php then $new_path = 'img/' . $imgName;

Comment: Ok. I fixed the form by adding there        <form action="addPost_form.php" method="post" class="row justify-content-center" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  And  the path is most likely correct - "forms/addPost_form.php'  and "img/somePicture".  here i go out of the forms folder into img.
But still doesn't work. I checked everything, I don't know where to look anymore

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use ../img; instead of just using /img, it will point out your root directory then the img folder. Another thing make sure $imgName has the image extension. If not, then concatenate the image extension with it. And it would be best if you stored the image extension on the database to read the image successfully. If image src directly does not print the image name and extension, you can store it separate variable, for example, `$image = $imgName.'.'.$imgExt` in this way.

Comment: Ok 
I changed the code a little, added checks and also checked everything with a debug function at each stage. The image goes all the way to $row->img. Аnd the name of the image and its extension are displayed here. It is possible that the whole thing is on the way. But the path is definitely correct. There are not many options

Comment: You should use / before $row->img but you're using .

Comment: Yes, sure. like this   <img src="/img/  <?= $row->img;?>"  alt="postik">. I apologize, I missed this moment here, but nevertheless, the problem remains. This is some kind of magic

Comment: It is working. Thank you very much. Apparently I do not have enough practice.

Comment: $row->img does it return with image extension. Can you inspect the image src path, check whether the image path is correct and the image exists in your intended folder. Open the path in the new tab of the browser by clicking on the mouse right button to see the image is working.

Comment: Yes, there is an image display. Everything worked already. Thank you again